# Steam doesn't work over tethered wifi through an android phone, how do i solve this?

Tags: tethering, wifi-tethering

So i tried to use my android phone that is connected to a wifi, and used a wifi sharing app called (Netshare), to tether the internet to my mac(wirelessly). The internet worked, the browser works and i can even go to the steam's website through my browser, but when i try to open the steam app it says its not able to connect.Any workarounds?

Ive tried to look for solutions but haven't found any yet. But AFAIK this likely seems to be the problem with UDP ports(which steam game clients require supposedly)and which the app doesn't seem to provide(thats what i think).

I mean, as i run the hotspot the app creates another network named "something", and tells me to connect to it and configure the HTTP and HTTPS proxy on my computer with `192.168.49.1:8282`and thats all. The internet does work but things like downloads and steam login doesn't.

So my question is,is there a way i could forward those ports or even make one (if thats whats needed)?

Sorry for a lame question but i don't know many technical terms.I just want to play DOTA on my mac tethering it wirelessly to my android phone, because the router is far away and i think this can be an alternative solution to buying an adapter(which i don't think is really necessary). Help.

Comment: Does it work if you use the phone's native WiFi Tethering? The app you are using seems to only acting as a proxy for http(s) which as you experience will let you browse the web, but that about it, leaving almost every other network service unusable.

Comment: @acejavelin yes, but i don't want to tether mobile data, but the wifi its connected to which the phone doesn't have natively.

Comment: what Android device doesn't have tethering built in? Or are you trying to bypass your carriers tethering restrictions

Comment: @acejavelin the scenario here is my android is phone is connected to a wifi and I want to share the intrenet coming through that wifi with my mac wirelessly which the app seems to be able to, but there are limitations as mentoined in the question(.Not trying to involve the native wifi tether /hotpot which requires mobile data if you want to add internet service to the hotspot.Whatsoever)

Comment: Gotcha... So your trying to make your phone a WiFi repeater basically. That doesn't work, Android has no capability of that. There are some root apps that allow the 5ghz radio to connect to WiFi and the 2.4ghz radio to act as an AP, but it's slow as WiFi is half-duplex and your doubling that. The solution your trying to use won't work. You would be better off picking up a cheap router that is DD-WRT capable and making it a repeater or bridge.

Comment: @acejavelin hey, do you have the link to that website or the app that you said would allow android phone to act as repeater, which you mentioned in the  comment above  by any means, I couldn't find it. Thanks anyways.